# Why doesn't the second Fade effect work? [FLEX]

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, fade, effects

I'm trying to apply some effects to a TileList; basicly when i remove an element from the list i want it to dissapear fading out, and when i add an element to the list i want it to appear fading in, quite simple no? well its not, the TileList component only has one effect to play with `itemsChangeEffect`, don't understand why there isn't a "itemsAddEffect" or "itemsRemoveEffect". So basicly i have created a sequence using filters to apply one fade to the items being added and another to the items being removed. This is my sequence:

```
<mx:Sequence id="dataChangeEffectSequence" effectStart="trace1(event)" effectEnd="trace2(event)">
    <mx:Fade duration="300" alphaFrom="1.0" alphaTo="0.0" perElementOffset="150" filter="removeItem"/>
    <mx:Fade duration="300" alphaFrom="0.0" alphaTo="1.0"  filter="addItem"/>
</mx:Sequence>
```

And this is my TileList:

```
 <mx:TileList id="list" dataProvider="{arrPro}" itemRenderer="compIdea.view.Thumb" width="100%" height="100%" 
                         itemClick="product_selected(event)" dragEnabled="true" dragComplete="updateCart()"
                         itemsChangeEffect="{dataChangeEffectSequence}"/>
```

The problem is that the fade i apply to the added items does not work, and the items are added to the tileList invisble(Faded out). It makes no sense, the fade doesn't do anything and the only way i have at least made the items appear in the tile list(Not faded out) is by doing this(don't understand why this works):

```
    <mx:Fade duration="300" alphaFrom="1.0" alphaTo="0.0" perElementOffset="150" filter="removeItem"/>

    <mx:Parallel>
        <mx:RemoveItemAction filter="removeItem"/>

        <mx:AddItemAction startDelay="200" filter="addItem"/>

        <mx:Fade duration="300" alphaFrom="0.0" alphaTo="1.0"  filter="addItem"/>
    </mx:Parallel>
</mx:Sequence>
```

Can someone please help me? i have also tried doing it from actionScript, but it gives me null Pointer and app dies..

Comment: Instead of filter="addItem" have you tried "replacedItem" or just "add" for the fade effect on the item being added?

Comment: Which version of Flex are you using?

Comment: Yes i have, if i dont use any filter, both effects work perfectly for all adds and removes. @Brian i'm using flex 3